# How to remove array value with reference to another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays which contains equal length:

```
var a = [a, b,c,d,e];
var b = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

I have another variable 'C' which contains one the value of array a

```
var c  = "d";
```

How do I remove '4' in another array 'b' based on the value of var C.

Final values required:

```
finala = [a,b,c,e];
finalb = [1,2,3,5];
removeda = d;
removedb = 4;
```

Comment: What id `a = [a,b,c,d,e,[1,2,3]]`

Comment: Does the array `a` contain strings or other variables?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) for the index and use [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) for both arrays.

```js
var a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
    b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    c = 'd',
    index = a.indexOf(c),
    removeda = a.splice(index, 1)[0],
    removedb = b.splice(index, 1)[0];

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
console.log(removeda);
console.log(removedb);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: The OP also wants the removed values stored.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work

```
var index = a.indexOf(c)
var removeda = a.splice(index, 1)[0];
var removedb = b.splice(index, 1)[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) and [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexof) methods.

```js
var a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
var b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var c = "d";

// get index of eleemnt in array `a`
var i = a.indexOf(c);

// remove element and store them in variable 
var removeda = a.splice(i, 1)[0],
  removedb = b.splice(i, 1)[0];

console.log(a, b, removeda, removedb)
```

Answer (score 0):

There you go.
Removing elements from both arrays, and storing what elements you removed:

```js
var a = ['a', 'b','c','d','e'],
    b = [1,2,3,4,5],
    c = "d",
    index = a.indexOf(c);

var removedA = a.splice(index, 1)[0];
var removedB = b.splice(index, 1)[0];
console.log(a);
console.log(removedA)
console.log(b);
console.log(removedB)
```